New tricycle back wheels locking up
I just had someone assemble my tricycle and when I went to ride it, the back wheels seize up. I am not sure what is happening to cause this?
Trike has a single driven rear wheel on the right-hand side, and mudguards/fenders.

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Some pictures might help, right now there's very little here to go on.

Great I will take some pictures tomorrow morning and post them. Thank you.

If you can't post pictures, can you atl east tell the make and model of the trike so that we can start guessing?

Photos would help a lot  (or even a short video), but my immediate suspicions are:

Brakes rubbing somewhere that they should not be rubbing
Incorrect assembly - something's just not right

Try lifting the trike off the ground and gently turn the wheels by hand, and observe what happens.   Don't use force, use your eyes..
Try turning the wheels or the cranks backward - I expect the chain to move but the wheels should stay still (if there's a freewheel) or if its a fixed-gear trike then the wheels should move backward.
Another gotcha is some tricycles drive both rear wheels, and some only drive a single rear wheel.
Finally - go back to whoever did the assembly and ask for a look-over for what was missed.  Clearly something's not right.

If the rear wheels can move independently you can turn the trike on one side to test (and work on) the wheel on the other side.

I took pics but I can’t upload them here for some reason. It is the right back wheel only. It is the wheel connected to the chain. When I hold up the trike it will not spin  The left wheel spins fine. The metal part that hovers above the tire is also on loosely. Sorry I do not know the technical names of things.

@user78341 whoever assembled it did an incomplete job.  Can you review the instructions and see what's not right ?  Maybe find someone else competent with their hands to help.
